# Extracting column default value from Parallel Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know, if it is possible to extract column default value from MS Parallel Data Warehouse. The problem is, the object_definition is not available on the PDW, so following code does not work. (It works on the MSSQL server though,)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT object_definition(default_object_id) AS definition
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  name      ='col1'
AND    object_id = object_id('dbo.tablename')
```

Is there any different way on the PDW?
Thank you

Comment: You could cheat by inserting a record, querying what was defaulted, and then deleting the record.

Comment: If that's possible it would probably be better in a transaction then rolled back.